# glob(os.path.join()) to work with the .npy data

Tags: python, numpy, glob

I am trying to augment [DC-GANS code](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py) so that it works with my data. The original code has its data as JPEG, however I would really strongly prefer to have my data in .npy.

The problem is line 76: `self.data = glob(os.path.join("./data", self.dataset_name, self.input_fname_pattern))` won't work with numpy data (it comes back blank, i.e. `[]`).

Hence I am wondering what's a good replacement for `glob(os.path.join())` for numpy files? Or are there any parameters that would make glob compatible with the numpy data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DCGAN.__init__`, change `input_fname_pattern='*.jpg'` to `input_fname_pattern='*.npy'`:

```
class DCGAN(object):
  def __init__(self, ...
               input_fname_pattern='*.npy'...):
```

This will change the *default* value of `input_fname_pattern` to `'*.npy'`.

Alternatively, when you instantiate `DCGAN`, you could pass `input_fname_pattern='*.npy'` to it:

```
dcgan = DCGAN(sess, input_fname_pattern='*.npy')
```

If you do one of those two things, then `glob(os.path.join("./data", self.dataset_name, self.input_fname_pattern))` will return any `.npy` file names in the `self.dataset_name` subdirectory of `./data`.